# Add path to sys.path vs. PEP E402

Tags: python, spyder, pep8

In order to import a project specific module somewhere located on your disk, one can easily append this directory to sys.path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(some_module_path)

import some_module
```

However, the latter import now violates PEP E402 ("module level import not at top of file"). At least spyder tells me so. Is spyder here too picky?

In spyder there is the principal idea of a "project", where I assumed environments can be adjusted specific for this project. However, I have no clue, how to modify e.g. the sys.path depending on a spyder project.

How can I modify sys.path in a spyder project? Or is there a general python way of solving this issue?

Comment: Use `PYTHONPATH` environment variable instead.

Comment: Install the module properly into a virtual environment. If it does not have a `setup.py`, write one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could put the `sys.path` extension in a separate module, e.g. `_paths.py`.

Contents of `_paths.py`:

```py
import sys

sys.path.append(some_module_path)
sys.path.append(some_other_module_path)
# ...and so on...
```

And then in your main application:

```py
import sys

import _paths
import some_module

some_module.some_func()
```

This solution puts your "project configuration" nicely in a single place (which makes it easy to maintain in the future), and complies with at least PEP8 (including E402) and pylint rules.

Comment: Nice work around but it adds a PyFlakes warning 'imported but unused'

Comment: @tricky in that case, time for `# noqa: W0611`.

Answer (score 3):

As alternative solution to the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185125/3883569) with a separate module if found this as working solution for me.

```
try:
    sys.path.append(Path(__file__).parent.parent)
except IndexError:
    pass
```

If I just use the `sys.path.append(...)`, I get the warning, but using the try-catch block does not produce a warning.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the question, but it may be helpful information.

You can import that module by directly specifying its path, without using `sys.path.append`

In Python 3 this is as simple as

```
import imp
some_module = imp.load_source('some_module', '/path/to/some_module.py')
```

More information here: [How to import a module given the full path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/how-to-import-a-module-given-the-full-path)

Comment: True. But please don't do this as a work-around for the problem mentioned in the question! Changing PYTHONPATH or ignoring the PEP warning for this specific scenario is a much better solution!

Comment: My issue with modifying PYTHONPATH as a general solution is that it affects all the scripts run by a user, unless you use `FOO=bar somecommand someargs` or some sort of virtualization.

Comment: I agree. I would create a batch file to setup the PYTHONPATH then, but I don't really like that solution as well. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185125/10669875) for a nicer solution :-)

Comment: @wovano nice solution, indeed!

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @wovano helped me a lot.

But since I was annoyed by the import warning I adapted the solution slightly.

File _paths.py:

```
import sys
import git
sys.path.append(git.Repo('.', search_parent_directories=True).working_tree_dir)

fix_import_warning = 'fix_import_warning'
```

In the file which does the imports:
During the imports:

```
import _paths
```

And then at the end:

```
def fix_import_warning(fix_import_warning = _paths.fix_import_warning):
    print(fix_import_warning)
```